# boto us-gov-west-1 region

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I try to list all instances in account, using code:

```
for region in boto.ec2.regions(**creds):
    print region.name
    ec2_conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region.name, **creds)

    for instance in ec2_conn.get_only_instances():
        print instance
```

But it fails when checking region "us-gov-west-1" with error:

boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized

`AuthFailure`AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentialsc873c473-c3b1-4be3-b562-b2e73b21e9c2

As I understand that region is some special goverment region not allowed for me to use. But how than ignore it? I can just wrap my loop in `try ... except` but may be there is some way to get the list of only accessible regions?

UPD: When iterating throught regions with following code:

```
ec2_conn = boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection(**creds)
for region in ec2_conn.get_all_regions():
```

gives no "us-gov-west-1" region. But why this methods give different results and when each should be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

[`boto.ec2.regions()`](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/ec2/__init__.py#L44) gives us list of all existing regions, which is hardcoded in the library, and

[`boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection::get_all_regions()`](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/ec2/connection.py#L3311) does actuall call to [`DescribeRegions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeRegions.html), to get list of regions currently available.

As somebody said: read the source Luke!

Comment: Also, I think you will need separate credentials or at least credentials that have been explicitly authorized for GovCloud.